# AWS Lambda+Redshift+Python:unable to import module. psycopg2 module not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I am trying to load data to redshift using AWS lambda function (python 2.7). Now, the function uses a psycopg2 package. So i downloaded  it, saved it to folder where my lambda function was already present and zipped it. The name of the zipped file is same as the function name(.py file). But when i test it, it gives me "unable to import module. psycopg2 module not found."
I searched and found this link : https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/3on09a/using_psycopg2_in_lambda/

I tried it as well but its not helping. Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error states 'psycopg2 module not found', chances are it could have failed to locate the dependency.
Below mentioned are few things that needs to be taken care of.

- Make sure that the psycopg2 package you have zipped along with lambda function is present in a folder named 'psycopg2', i.e., zip file should include your lambda function and a folder named 'psycopg2' containing the dependencies.
- Also make sure that the deployment package is compatible with Linux. Lambda underneath runs AMI images, which is based on linux.

You can find the required package for your Lambda function [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/29/dc/bf65b06574324222e1a9fd2c80a3acdc0b77d5812ac3d0568dede83d6a50/psycopg2-2.7.3.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=52d98207b8f3177587300e0d5697939f).